# Does SO_ATTACH_FILTER reset the socket's receive buffer?

Tags: linux, c, socket, filter

If a filter is already set and there are unprocessed packets in the sockets receive buffer will calling SO_ATTACH_FILTER to set a new updated filter flush the buffer, i.e is it the same as BSD's BIOCSETF which "Flushes the buffer of incoming packets, and resets the statistics that are returned by BIOCGSTATS.".

If so is there an equivalent of BIOCSETFNR for the Linux socket which will not flush the receive buffer?